# How to create a custom loss function from sklearn metrics in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I'd like to use the mutual information metric from sklearn as a loss function for a neural network in Keras, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'd like to try this because relationships in my dataset are non-linear and I believe it would help to use this metric instead.

Posts about creating custom loss function are more than a year old so I was hoping there was maybe some easier way to do this as some of it goes above my head.

Any idea about how to go about this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do any of the following answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/43818584/781723, https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/369, https://stackoverflow.com/q/45961428/781723

Comment: It does but I'm just not sure how to implement it, I'll give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [cross-entropy loss function](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html#the_cross-entropy_cost_function).  That is already built into Keras, and while you haven't defined exactly what you mean by "mutual information metric", if it's what I suspect you mean, it is equivalent to the cross-entropy loss.

Comment: I'm talking about using [this score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mutual_info_score.html) instead of [cross-entropy](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) is my understanding that they are different, incorrect?

Comment: @DiogenicOrder, please edit your question to clarify what you are asking, and include a self-contained definition of what you mean by mutual information metric.  As it stands I'm forced to guess what you might mean.  For instance, the page you link to talks about clustering; but it sounds like you are trying to do classification, so it's not entirely clear to me how you plan to apply that metric to your situation.  In any case, don't make me guess; spell it out in the question.